# Is the generalized coherent state orthogonal to the photon added coherent state of the same number?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, coherent-states

How is a generalized coherent state $|m,\alpha\rangle$ different from a photon added coherent state $|\alpha,m\rangle$ ? And are they orthogonal?

Comment: It would help if you explained a bit more of the context here or explained what your definition of the states $\lvert m,\alpha\rangle$ or $\lvert \alpha,m\rangle$. Sadly, you cannot just assume that everyone uses the same terminology and notation for the same things.

Comment: Indeed, notation here is not standardised enough for one to be able to use those terms without providing explicit definitions. There are multiple ways to generalise coherent states and to add photons to them, and you need to specify which one you're talking about.